# How to use bootstrap datetimepicker in laravel edit form?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am doing project in laravel. I have used bootstrap datetimepicker while editing form.

**edit.blade** looks like,

```
{!! Form::model($event,['method' => 'PATCH','files'=>true,'action'=>['EventController@update',$event->id]]) !!}
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
     <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
     <div class="input-group date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
        <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" name="start_date" value="{{$event_schedule->start_date or ''}}" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
     </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" /><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
     <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
     <div class="input-group date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
      <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" name="end_date" value="{{$event_schedule->end_date or ''}}" readonly>
       <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
     </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" /><br/>
 </div>
</div>

{!!Forrm::close()!!}
```

when I submit this form and return request::all() from my controller method then does't return any date as result.

I don't know how to get this date so that I can edit form data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove

```
 or ''
```

from value then you will get your date values using request.

Comment: If I remove (or ' ') then it won't show me that database date value by default

Comment: You can use by default data from database. If you set date fields type is date, it will be get default data if value is not set. Anyway In edit page can you see date which you saved before?

Comment: Did you see any error occurred when submit your edit form? and check by the dd($request->all()) this syntax. and check attributes. at first remove or '' from values.

Comment: Hey thanks, after doing dd($request->all()) its showing date, while not after doing only return

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" name="end_date" value="
 {{date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($event_schedule->end_date))}}" readonly>
```

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience..Thank you